# how to count special char without a-z , 0-9 , underscore , dash and full stop?

Tags: php

How to count special char without a-z , 0-9 , underscore , dash and full stop ?
I tried many times but didn't managed to make it work.

for example : `asd -_.`

count = 1 (for space bar)

and : `1234!@#$,,`

count = 6 (for `!@#$,,` )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
strlen(preg_replace('@[a-z0-9_\-\.]@', '', $string));
```

This first removes all characters you do not want: a-z, 0-9 _ - and . by preg_replace

```
preg_replace('@[a-z0-9_\-\.]@', '', $string);
```

Then calculates the length of resulting string

Comment: I think OP wants to remove a-z0-9... and not keep it. Remove the `^` and it should work as required.

Comment: this code `strlen(preg_replace('@[a-z0-9_\-\.]@', '', $string));`

will be remove a-z 0-9 - _ .

Comment: `preg_replace(..)` removes given character and `strlen` calculates the length of resulting string

Comment: for 1 question if i want to count only a-z and 0-9 how can i do ?

Comment: in that case you can remove all characters except a-z and 0-9. This is done by `preg_replace('@[^a-z0-9]@', '', $string);`.